# Syntax error creating table with constraints

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl

I've created 4 other tables, but can't get this to run.  I'm sure it has to do with:

```
AgentID varchar2(4), CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY Riders_AgentId_FK REFERENCES Agents(AgentID)
```

But I don't know what to change....

```
CREATE TABLE Riders(
RiderID varchar2(4) CONSTRAINT Riders_RiderID_PK PRIMARY KEY ,
FirstName VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT Riders_FirstName_NN NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT Riders_LastName_NN NOT NULL,
Street VARCHAR(255),
City VARCHAR(255),
State VARCHAR(255),
Zip varchar(255),
Phone varchar(255),
DateJoined DATE,
AgentID varchar2(4), CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY Riders_AgentId_FK REFERENCES Agents(AgentID),
TeamID varchar2(4)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this line (the name of the constraint is given after the keyword `CONSTRAINT`:

```
AgentID varchar2(4) CONSTRAINT Riders_AgentId_FK FOREIGN KEY(AgentID) REFERENCES Agents(AgentID),
```

in:

```
CREATE TABLE Riders(
RiderID varchar2(4) CONSTRAINT Riders_RiderID_PK PRIMARY KEY ,
FirstName VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT Riders_FirstName_NN NOT NULL,
LastName VARCHAR(255) CONSTRAINT Riders_LastName_NN NOT NULL,
Street VARCHAR(255),
City VARCHAR(255),
State VARCHAR(255),
Zip varchar(255),
Phone varchar(255),
DateJoined DATE,
AgentID varchar2(4) CONSTRAINT Riders_AgentId_FK FOREIGN KEY(AgentID) REFERENCES Agents(AgentID),
TeamID varchar2(4)
);
```

A couple of other notes:

- the "id" fields probably should be `NUMBER` (`RiderID`, `AgentID`, `AgentID` in the
  `Agents` table)
- the `varchar` fields probably should be `varchar2`